# Query db for getting list either like given name, email or phone

Tags: android, sqlite, selection, projection, android-cursor

I want to get contacts list which is

```
1. LIKE given text display_name  **OR**

2. LIKE given text email   **OR**

3. LIKE given text phone no
```

Following is my query

```
String text = "testing";
    ContentResolver cr = getContentResolver();

    String[] mSelectionArgs = {  "%" + text + "%" };

    String SELECTION =
            (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB ?
                    ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME_PRIMARY + " LIKE ?" :
                    ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME + " LIKE ?")
            + " OR  " +ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER + " LIKE ?"
                    + " OR  " + ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.DATA+ " LIKE ?"
            ;

    Cursor cursor = cr.query(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI, null,
            SELECTION, mSelectionArgs, null);

android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such column: data1 (code 1): , while compiling: SELECT times_contacted, contacts_status_updates.status AS contact_status, phonetic_name, phonetic_name_style, link_accounts AS link, is_user_profile, lookup, phonebook_label_alt, contacts_status_updates.status_icon AS contact_status_icon, last_time_contacted, contact_last_updated_timestamp, sec_custom_vibration, _id, display_name_source, photo_uri, photo_thumb_uri, agg_presence.chat_capability AS contact_chat_capability, photo_id, send_to_voicemail, display_name_alt AS display_name_reverse, custom_ringtone, name_raw_contact_id, photo_file_id, has_phone_number, contacts_status_updates.status_label AS contact_status_label, link_type1, phonebook_bucket, display_name, phonebook_bucket_alt, has_email, sort_key_alt, phonebook_label, dirty_contact, in_visible_group, starred, link_count, display_name_alt, sort_key, agg_presence.mode AS contact_presence, sec_custom_alert, is_private, contacts_status_updates.status_res_package AS contact_status_res_package, contacts_status_updates.status_ts AS contact_status_ts FROM view_contacts_restricted LEFT OUTER JOIN agg_presence ON (view_contacts_restricted._id = agg_presence.presence_contact_id) LEFT OUTER JOIN status_updates contacts_status_updates ON (status_update_id=contacts_status_updates.status_update_data_id) WHERE ((1)) AND (((display_name LIKE ?) OR  (data1 LIKE ?) OR  (data1 LIKE ? )))
                                                                                      at android.database.DatabaseUtils.readExceptionFromParcel(DatabaseUtils.java:181)
                                                                                      at android.database.DatabaseUtils.readExceptionFromParcel(DatabaseUtils.java:137)
                                                                                      at android.content.ContentProviderProxy.query(ContentProviderNative.java:385)
                                                                                      at android.content.ContentResolver.query(ContentResolver.java:417)
                                                                                      at android.content.ContentResolver.query(ContentResolver.java:360)
                                                                                      at com.icpl.dhrupalpatel.searchconatact.MainActivity.getDetail(MainActivity.java:81)
                                                                                      at com.icpl.dhrupalpatel.searchconatact.MainActivity$1.onClick(MainActivity.java:49)
                                                                                      at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4475)
                                                                                      at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18796)
                                                                                      at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:730)
                                                                                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
                                                                                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
                                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5455)
                                                                                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                                                                                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
                                                                                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1187)
                                                                                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1003)
                                                                                      at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: what are you retrieving with that query? which is the error if there is one? you are missing the problem in que question

Comment: Added ? also after 3nd and 4th like

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it by using ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_FILTER_URI. [This](https://medium.com/@dhrupal1987/read-contacts-like-native-phone-search-do-without-fetching-all-contacts-2d004e655e1d#.myjux2b6y) is link.

Answer (score -1):

As you can see in the error, `data1` doesn't exists in the table.

Your query has this statement: `OR  (data1 LIKE ?) OR  (data1 LIKE ? )`. probably it's an error but in any case check it.

There are 2 possibilities:

1. Check where this `data1` is and use `TABLENAME.data1 LIKE ...`
2. The column `data1` doesn't exists in any table and it's an error. In this case, add it into a table by editing the db.

Check if this column exists and use tablename.field for all where conditions.

**EDIT**

Look the official guide on how to retrieve a contact list from android devices [here](https://developer.android.com/training/contacts-provider/retrieve-names.html)

*NOTE: READ ALL THE POST AND NOT ONLY THE FIRST ROW*

hope this helps

Comment: Is it because I am trying to find Phone.NUMBER and Email.DATA which belongs to ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds and URI is of ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI?

Comment: @Dhrupal ok. but you don't have the column named "data1" anywhere in your db. if you have, instead of "data1 LIKE ?". use "tablename.data1 LIKE ?"

Comment: It's contacts database. I am trying to read device's contacts. Data1 is not defined anywhere. And its throwing exception at the time of cr.query.

Comment: I know it's not defined. but you are using it. anyway explain better the question and read the error. the error is "no such column: data1" so it means you are using it (in the where clause) but it doesn't exists. read [here how to retrieve contacts](https://developer.android.com/training/contacts-provider/retrieve-names.html)

Comment: It is getting all contacts and then search, I want to search directly using query.

Comment: @Dhrupal you didn't read all the page. it's not written in the first chapter and you didn't read the ones below. I give up.